# Fetch Merchant Name from Transaction SMS - Android

Tags: android, parsing, sms

I want to fetch Merchant Name from Bank Transaction SMS. For this I used following regx;

```
Pattern.compile("(?i)(?:\\sat\\s|in\\*)([A-Za-z0-9]*\\s?-?\\s?[A-Za-z0-9]*\\s?-?\\.?)")
```

Its works fine with those SMS which contains **at** / **in** but what if SMS contains other than this two words.
For example, SMS is like ;

> Dear Customer, You have made a Debit Card purchase of INR1,600.00 on
>   30 Jan. Info.VPS*AGGARWAL SH.

Then how to fetch **AGGARWAL SH** from above SMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this below code to fetch Merchant Name from String

```
private void extractMerchantNameFromSMS(){
    try{
        String mMessage= "Dear Customer, You have made a Debit Card purchase of INR1,600.00 on 30 Jan. Info.VPS*AGGARWAL SH.";
        Pattern regEx = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?:\\sInfo.\\s*)([A-Za-z0-9*]*\\s?-?\\s?[A-Za-z0-9*]*\\s?-?\\.?)");
        // Find instance of pattern matches
        Matcher m = regEx.matcher(mMessage);
        if(m.find()){
            String mMerchantName = m.group();
            mMerchantName = mMerchantName.replaceAll("^\\s+|\\s+$", "");//trim from start and end
            mMerchantName = mMerchantName.replace("Info.","");
            FileLog.e(TAG, "MERCHANT NAME : "+mMerchantName);
        }else{
            FileLog.e(TAG, "MATCH NOTFOUND");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        FileLog.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: How to make a general algorithm for detecting vendors from multiple types of sms? any ideas?